# can I download file from ftp without save it my directory first

Tags: java, spring, ftp

I have a page download, where the file you want to download must be downloaded first from other server use ftp.
i use this code to download from ftp:

```
ftpClient.connect(server, port);
ftpClient.login(user, pass);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

String remoteFile1 = "/Users/A/file.txt";
File downloadFile1 = new File("/Users/B/Downloads/file.txt");
OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
outputStream1.close();
```

if i use this program, i need to save file.txt in my directory /Users/B/Downloads/ then i need to use my other code to download file.txt from /Users/B/Downloads/.

is it possible if i download the file.txt without save it first in my directory /Users/B/Downloads/?

Comment: Yes it is. Use a different outputStream then a FileOutputStream

Comment: @Jens how to do it in this code? could you explain it to me?

Comment: Does one of the answers solve the problem? If so, could you mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark to the left. That way, it will no longer turn up in the list of unsolved questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ByteArrayOutputStream instead of BufferedOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
String fileContent = outputStream1.toString("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

To write to a stream, in memory, use: [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Another Way:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
String remoteFile1 = "/Users/A/file.txt";
try {
   InputStream stream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile1);
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
   int data;
   while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
      //here, do what ever you want
   }
} finally {
   if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException ex) {}
}
```